# Icons not showing up next to my bullet text?

Tags: html

I have a web page I'm designing, and I am trying to have icons appear in front of text as bullet points.  The relevant code is as follows:

CSS file:

```
.content .bullets {
    float: left;
}

.content .bullets {
    margin: 5px 0;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
    width: 400px;
}

.content .bullets ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
}

.content .bullets ul li {
    padding: 0 0 10px 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #4675b5;
}

/* icons */
.connect_ico {background: url(/images/Apartment Favicon.png) 0 5px no-repeat;}
.impress_ico {background: url(/images/resume favicon.png) 0 5px no-repeat;}
.living_ico {background: url(/images/ThumbsUp Favicon.png) 0 5px no-repeat;}
```

index.html:

```
<div class="bullets">
            <ul>
                <li class="connect_ico">Example text......</li>
                <br>
                <li class="impress_ico">Example Text.....</li>
                <br>
                <li class="living_icon">Examples Text......</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Obviously these are just pieces of the code, but I think they are the relevant pieces.  I have uploaded these images to the images directory on my FTP server, and I am using Cyberduck (on a Mac).

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to remove the spaces in your .png images. Also you can do this in a much easier way by creating an `<ul>` and using css to replace the bullets in the list with images:

```
ul {
list-style-image: url(images/ThumbsUpFavicon.png);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/` at the beginning of the image urls. That's an absolute path, you probably want relative ones. Also, spaces might need to be escaped with a backlash, like so: `foo\ bar.png`

Comment: Thanks Michael, the spaces in the image names were the problem.  After I removed those, they appeared just fine.